# perl cgi, awstats tool and modification

Tags: perl, cgi

In awstats tool, it creates some log files in a ./data folder.

I was wondering which script creates these log files? My purpose is to remove myself from tracking list since I am the one building the site.

thanks
Gordon

Comment: it should be awstats.pl, I do not understand your goal, can you be more specific ?

Comment: i would like to remove any tracking stats of me (as a user) since I visit the website all the time and do mainly script building and testing on the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ... so : http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#EXCLUDEHOSTS

regards

Comment: also found this: SkipUserAgents
Version : 5.1+ (5.6+ for REGEX syntax)

# Do not include access from clients with a user agent that match following
# criteria. If you want to exclude a robot, you should update the robots.pm
# file instead of this parameter.
# The opposite parameter of "SkipUserAgents" is "OnlyUserAgents".
# Note: Use space between each value. This parameter is not case sensitive.
# Note: You can use regular expression values writing value with REGEX[value].
# Change : Effective for new updates only
# Example: "konqueror REGEX[ua_test_v\d\.\d]"
# Default: ""
#
SkipUserAgents=